# Algorithm to compute average direction of undirected segments

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a set of 2D undirected segments, composed of two end-points. Statistically most of them are lying in more or less the same direction.

What I'd like to compute is the average **direction** of the segment set (for example if the set is globally N/S, it would return something ~ 0°, etc...). Note that I do not care which actual direction is returned (0° or 180° will equally do).

Clamping the direction of each segment in the [0..180°[ range and taking the average does not work (for example two segments, one 1° and the other -1°: the second will clamp to 179° and the average is wrong, here 90°, should be 0°).

I was also thinking of clustering the "normalized segments" end-points in two groups, and computing the direction of the segment composed of the 2 clusters mid-points, but that seems a bit complicated for the task. By "normalized segment" I mean the segment having both end-points on the unit-circle and the middle point at the origin.

Is there an known algorithm/formula for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand the location of segments does not matter, only their direction.

So we can change the problem a bit: we have a set of vectors and we want to fit a line on them.

We can take different criteria for this. A commonly used one is least squares.

For this criteria the solution is:

```
double dvx=0,dvy=0;
for(const auto &direction:directions)
{
    dvx+=2*direction.dx*direction.dy;
    dvy+=squared(directions.dx)-squared(directions.dy);
}
return std::atan2(dvx,dvy)/2;//or may be +pi/2
```

Note: for this implementation directions will be weighted by their length,  if you want to assign the same weight, direction vectors should be normalized.

This method is sometimes used in determining direction of lines in fingerprints recognition: http://jmit.us.edu.pl/cms/jmitjrn/22/28_Wieclaw_4.pdf

There are several ways to understand this method. One of them is geometrical:

We have a set of vectors with angle `alpha[i]` from X axis. We don't average these vectors. Instead we build vectors with angle `2*alpha[i]`, average them and take the half of the resulting angle. The trick is that if opposite directions differ by `pi` and after doubling they will differ by `2*pi` which is no difference at all.

Comment: As I understand, this will average *vectors*. I have *undirected segments*, so the segment and his opposite (both ends points swapped) should be considered the same.

Comment: @LaurentGrégoire, please see the explanation I've added to the end

Comment: Excellent, indeed the trick is to average bearings multiplied by 2, then halve this average. Btw for my need, I used a simple weighted average of the sines and cosines.

Comment: (0° + 180°)/2 = 90°, but (2*0° + 2*180°)/2 = 180°, half the result is still 90°. Something is missing here.

Comment: @JannPoppinga, it's not the angles being averaged, but vectors (their coordinates)

Answer (score 2):

There [is method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities) to find mean of angles (in full circular range)

```
MeanAngle = ArcTan2(Sum{i=1..n}(Sin(Alpha[i])), Sum{i}(Cos(Alpha[i])))
```

It seems that for you case you can calculate mean of Cosines of direction vectors (because Cos(-alpha) = Cos(alpha)), and get ArcCos (in range 0..Pi)

```
MeanAngleWithoutDir = ArcCos(1/n * Sum{i=1..n}(Cos(Alpha[i])))
```

Probably angles should be clamped to (0..Pi) or (-Pi/2..Pi/2) range to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: That does not work. For the simple case of two segments, one at 10° and the other at -10° your formula gives a mean of 10°, whereas the expected solution is 0°.

Comment: @Laurent Grégoire  I doubt in problem formullation again: `Mean(-10.10) = 0`. But for your purposes `-10 = 170` . `Mean(170, 10) = 90`. Contradiction... Is this problem solvable?

Comment: This problem is definitively solvable, see my answer. The trick is indeed to handle the modulo 180° well. Averaging the angle modulo 180° is obviously wrong (-10° and 10° is a simple example where the expected answer is 0°, not 90°).

Answer (score 2):

Meta note: this answer calculates the “median” of the given lines.
The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36570929/1488799) by MBo calculates the “mean” of the given lines.

---

Let us formalize the problem in the following way.
We are given a collection of lines, and we want to find a line *p* such that the sum of angles between *p* and all given lines is the minimum possible.
Here, an angle between two lines is the minimal of the angles at their intersection point, or 0 if they are parallel or coincide.
Thus, an angle between two lines is always from 0 to 90 degrees.

To make things simpler to reason about, translate the lines so that they all pass through the origin.
Obviously, this would not affect the answer.

---

To solve this, let us study the derivative of the said sum.
Suppose we have an answer line *p*.
Let there be *x* lines which are 0-90 degrees clockwise from *p*, and *y* lines which are 0-90 degrees counter-clockwise from *p* (*x + y = n*, the total number of lines given).

Now, rotate *p* by a small angle *α* clockwise.
The answer will decrease by *x * α* and increase by *y * α*.
So, if *x > y*, the answer will decrease, and if *x < y*, it will increase.

There are two cases where the quantities *x* and *y* change.

1. The line *p* coincides with one of the given lines.
2. The line *q* is orthogonal to one of the given lines.

Between any two such consecutive points on the circle, the derivative of our sum will be the constant *x - y*.
So, the minimum will be at one of the “angles of interest”: either parallel or orthogonal to some of the given lines.
This leads to *O(n^2)* algorithm: for each of the *O(n)* angles of interest, just compute the sum in *O(n)*, and choose the angle which gives the minimum sum.

---

This can be accelerated further to *O(n log n)*.

1. Generate the *2 n* angles of interest in *O(n)*.
2. Sort them in *O(n log n)*.
3. Compute the answer, and also *x* and *y*, for the first such angle in *O(n)*.
4. Move along the circle, maintaining the current answer and the values *x* and *y*.
   In each of the *O(n)* steps, calculations can be done in *O(1)*.

Comment: This median approach looks interesting, but can't easily accommodate segment weighting. O(n^2) is a no-go for large dataset.

Comment: @LaurentGrégoire But it can. Instead of _x_ and _y_ segments of weight 1, we will have segments of total weight _X_ clockwise and segments of total weight _Y_ counter-clockwise. The rest of the argument stays exactly the same.

Comment: @LaurentGrégoire _O(n^2)_ is the trivial implementation. As stated below, it can be accelerated to _O(n log n)_ if need be. If it is not clear, please point out what exactly needs additional explanation.

Comment: @LaurentGrégoire On another note, please state the requirements you have (weighted segments, feasible asymptotic behavior, etc.) clearly in the question itself.

Comment: Segment weight is optional, and many classes of algorithms can be tweaked easily to accommodate it if needed. I did not included it to not add too much complexity in my question. Your algorithm is fine; it's just that the other solution in O(n) is faster and probably simpler to implement.

Comment: @LaurentGrégoire Simpler, sure: solution by MBo is a few lines, this one is perhaps 10-30 lines. As to whether it's faster, most probably, but _O(n log n)_ sort and _O(n)_ additional processing would also be fine in most cases. I'd speculate that the relevance of result matters more than speed and simplicity. The solutions compute different quantities ("mean" vs. "median"), and what could matter is which one comes closer to what you actually need.

Answer (score 2):

> Statistically most of them are lying in more or less the same
>   direction.

This key bit of info will have critical importance in the design of your algorithm. If you **know** that all your vectors lie within a 90 degree cone you can use a very simple method:

- take the dot product of the first normalized direction vector with all the rest
- flip any vectors that return a negative dot product
- average the resulting vectors as usual

If you need to handle a wider distribution you can modify this slightly:

- sum your normalized direction vectors one at a time
- before adding a vector, compute its dot product with your current sum
- if the dot product is negative flip the vector before adding it to the sum
- normalize your sum

This is a serial algorithm but if you need higher performance this can be easily formulated as a parallel reduction:

- for each normalized vector pair in the reduction tree

  - take the dot product of the pair
  - if it is negative flip one of the two vectors and sum them
  - pass the sum to the next stage of the reduction
- normalize your final sum

Any of these methods can easily be weighted as you only care about the sign of the dot product.

Comment: Unfortunately, not *all* of them will be in the 90° cone. But the bulk of them will probably be rather grouped around the mean. My dataset does have a Gaussian-like distribution around the mean, with a standard deviation between I would say 10-20°.

Answer (score 1):

Below a `O(n)` solution, that can also accommodate an optional weight for each segment.

We model each segment by it's angle with the X axis (a) with a weight (w). The segment direction is not important at this point, any value modulo 180° will do. The idea is to loop for each segment and keeping track of the average direction computed so far; and adjust this average with the direction modulo 180 that is closer to the average itself.

Pseudo-code (all angles in degrees):

```
aa = 0
ww = 0
for a, w in segments:
    // Compute delta between angles in range [-180°..+180°[
    da = a - aa
    if da < -180:
       da += 360
    if da >= 180:
       da -= 360
    // Optional direction swap, delta in [-90°..+90°[
    if da < -90:
       da += 180
    if da >= 90:
       da -= 180
    // The following formula also make sure aa = a mod 180
    // when ww = 0 (first iteration).
    aa += da * w / (w + ww)
    ww += w
    // Clamp result to [0°..+360°[
    if aa >= 360:
       aa -= 360
    if aa < 0:
       aa += 360
// Clamp final result aa to [0..+180°[ (optional step)
if aa > 180:
    aa -= 180
```

I did not demonstrated that the result is independent from the iteration order, but at first glance of the algorithm it should be.

---

## On the dependency of this algorithm vs input iteration order

For well-behaved input data, the algorithm is very stable regardless of iteration order.

However, as soon as the input data does not have a clear-cut main direction, this result of this algorithm **will strongly depend on the iteration order**, in an hard to predict chaotic mode.

Numerical simulation shows that for random directions with a standard deviation of **less than 20°** (around the median) the algorithm seems to be always stable. With standard deviation greater than 20° numerical instabilities start to appears and the result strongly depends on the iteration order (between 20° and 30° the difference is probably small enough to ignore, over 30° large difference start to appear).

I did not precisely computed the exact chaotic/stable standard deviation cut-off, so take this 20° value as an initial guess. An exact mathematical solution is left as an exercise to the reader.

Below a result of a numerical simulation (for each standard deviation from 0 to 45°, run 1000 times the algorithm on various random data of given standard deviation, and measure the average delta between 10 runs).

[image: Average deviation between runs vs input data standard deviation around mean]

Thus, for best results, if your input data is not guaranteed to have a small standard deviation, it's probably best to order the input data on a stable key (bigger weight first, or any other key depending on your input).